# Error while upgrading 17.10 to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

I got following error while running `sudo update-manager -d` command. Why this error occurred? And how to solve it?

```
sudo update-manager -d
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(update-manager:2298): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

Comment: What i wonder is, why you try to update to the development version, which might actually not exist anymore because of today is release day?

Comment: @Videonauth just for learning purpose. I followed this steps . https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-ubuntu-version/

Comment: You shouldn't use `update-manager -d` to upgrade Ubuntu to 18.04 manually.  You should use `do-release-upgrade` on the command line to upgrade, at least once 18.04 is released.  **However, 18.04 is not yet officially released at this moment**, so your results in upgrading might vary.